# Which pattern implemented in ASP.NET web form?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm interested which pattern has been implemented in ASP.NET web form? Is it smth like MVP/Smart UI or maybe one of Code Behind(Presenter) patterns?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx#S8

Answer (score 0):

It's really a combination of patterns and partial patterns.  WebForms consists of a lot of different things, and as such has many concepts in them, and many of those concepts match up to, or are variations of many other patterns.

Richard posted a link to a great article.

The MVP pattern (P stands for Presenter) was designed to address typical SDLC problems with WebForms, so WebForms are not MVP, but you can use MVP with WebForms (you have to write the MVP code yourself).